# Forwarding an internet connection

Tags: internet, connection, remote, connection-sharing

Wondering if i could tap into all your deep knowledge of internet of things and get some assistance with the following.

I work from home, and am getting married in brazil. I want to keep working but i want to retain my connection from canada. To get dual citizenship it requires me to stay in brazil for up to 3 months.

I have my place in toronto, and was wondering if there would be a way to configure my box in toronto to accept my connection from brazil so it would seem i am in canada.

What can i do to accomplish this and what would be the pro's / con's of doing this around latency.

Workstation for work is a cloud computing device ( wyse ) and the box in toronto can be configured to do anything.

Speeds of internet in Toronto can be 80 down and 10 upload.
Speeds of internet in Brazil can be 60 down and 2 - 4 upload.

I appreciate any help / suggestions in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

The Best solution will to setup a VPN Server on your box in Canada. If your Router in Canada have VPN server functionality then you can setup a VPN on it and when you are in Brazil simply connect your PC to a VPN using native client of the operating system your are using. It will seems like your on your Canada network. so simple steps are

1. Setup VPN Serve on your Router or Computer in Canada and leave it running.
2. Connect your PC to your VPN using VPN client.

OpenVPN can be one solution to setup a vpn server and client.
https://openvpn.net/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I'll do some testing on the next week to verify strength of this. Again thank you